# Excel Sumifs with index match

Tags: excel, indexing, match, sumifs

I'm trying to write a formula that gives me the following output:

[image]

The information is gathered from here:

[image]

The formula I have used is `=SUMIFS(INDEX(Planning!$AU$493:$FF$497,,MATCH('Resource overview'!AY1,Planning!AU1:FF1,0)),Planning!$G$493:$G$497,'Resource overview'!AY2)`

But this gives me the following output:

[image]

This is wrong, I want to be able to `SUM` the amounts for the entire row where e.g. App and 2021-06-01 occurs, so in this case I want to get `11 937.5 (2387.5+2387.5+2387.5+2387.5+2387.5)`

How can I tweak the code to get the desired result?

Comment: Looks like you want: `=SUMIF(Planning!$AU$1:$FF$1,'Resource overview'!AY$1,INDEX(Planning!$AU$493:$FF$497,1,MATCH('Resource overview'!AY$2,Planning!$G$493:$G$497,0)))`

Comment: Hi it works for the first cell below App, but when you drag the formula out it gives the exact same value for Dev etc. It has to be dynamic so that it corresponds to App, Dev, PO, SDM and PM.

Comment: I think you must have copied it wrong then, or you have calculation set to manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMIFS(OFFSET(Planning!$AU$493:$FF$493,MATCH('Resource overview'!AY$2,Planning!$G$493:$G$497,0)-1,0),Planning!$AU$1:$FF$1,'Resource overview'!AY$1)
```

should do..

Idea : "shift" the `sumifs` range with `offset` & `match` (text match). The `sumifs` criteria defines the date match.

p/s : somehow the trick work for `countif`/`countblank` .. but it doesn't work for `sumif`

Please share if it works/not.